# MinIfs syntax with conditional time/date

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use the `MinIfs` method of the `WorksheetFunction` object to determine a conditional minimum.
Adding another condition makes my code fail, resulting in 0, which suggests that the last condition is not satisfied in the used range. But in fact it is.

What I need help with is the correct syntax of the last condition.

What works:

```
WorksheetFunction.MinIfs(wsSource.Columns(34), wsSource.Columns(36), False, wsSource.Columns(14), False, wsSource.Columns(3), wsL.Cells(j, 13).Value)
```

What doesn't:

```
WorksheetFunction.MinIfs(wsSource.Columns(34), wsSource.Columns(36), False, wsSource.Columns(14), False, wsSource.Columns(3), wsL.Cells(j, 13).Value, wsSource.Columns(34), """>""&" & startTime)
```

The variable `startTime` is defined as a date, and contains date and time information. Column 34 contains date and time information in custom format that looks like this: `2021.01.04  22:20:07`.

What the code is trying to do is to find the earliest time and date that fits the other criteria after a certain time of that specific day (stored in `startTime`).

Changing format, however, shouldn't matter, and in fact it doesn't: I changed the source's format to number and it hadn't worked either. I tried to replace `startTime` with `CDbl(startTime)` as well.

Comment: No need for the & in "'s before `& startTime`

Comment: I think you have extra quotes too: try `">" & startTime`.

Comment: I'll give these a try. I removed both at some point, but probably not both at the same time.
But I need the & if I write the function into a cell, so if I don't need the extra &, I don't understand this at all.

Comment: BigBen's doesn't seem to work. @Nathan_Sav, can you please write the whole thing that you'd write after the Column(34), part?

Comment: Okay, so... ">" & 1 works. 
This means a couple of things. BigBen is right, no need for either of the extra quotes or the first & sign.
The problem is apparently with the startTime variable.

This question is answered, why startTime failed to work is beyond me. It even shows I have what I want to have in it, and CDbl(startTime) is clearly a number, not unlike 1, which worked. Sigh.

Comment: Okay, so actual solution to the problem found here.
I replaced the criteria range definitions, which previously worked in the worksheetvariable.Columns(column number) format with worksheetvariable.Range(worksheetvariable.Cells(2, column number), worksheetvariable.Cells(worksheetvariable.Usedrange.Rows.Count, column number) format and it works. 

How is that even possible!? I can understand that there is a difference between ws.columns(num) and ws.range(definition), but if one worked earlier, how can it stop working if i add one more criteria?!